# Proving a supremum is not in a certain set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

The question is as follows:

> Let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $x \in A.$ Prove that if $B \equiv \left \{ b \in (x, \infty) \mid [x,b) \subset A \right \}$ is bounded, then $\sup B \notin A.$

I thought this question seemed difficult initially, but now I think it is quite trivial.

Clearly, $x<b.$

We know that the set $A$ has a supremum since it is nonempty and bounded. If we take $x \in A$ to be very close to $\sup A$, the number $b$ can only be ever be as big as $\sup A.$ If $b = \sup A + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$, then $[x,b)$ would not be a subset of $A.$

Therefore, $\max{b}=\sup A$, which implies that $\sup A = \sup B.$  Since $A$ is open, $\sup A \notin A$.  Thus we can conclude that $\sup B \notin A.$  $\blacksquare$

I think I am looking at the question incorrectly.  Would anyone know how to complete this proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "$A$ is nonempty and bounded". I agree that it is non-empty, since $x\in A$, but why is it bounded?

Comment: Good point.  If $A$ is not bounded, then I would have no idea where to start with this.  I would assume it is false at first look.  Now I am more confused, haha.

Comment: It looks like a proof by contradiction. You consider two cases, when $\sup B$ is finite, and when it isn't. If it's finite, then there's neighbourhood of $\sup B$ that is in $A$. You draw a conclusion that $\sup B$ is less than a point from $B$, which is a contradiction with the fact that $\sup B\in A$

Comment: Thanks. And if it’s infinite?

Comment: If $B$ has no upper bound in $\Bbb R$ then no member of $\Bbb R$ (and , a fortiori, no member of $A$) is equal to $\sup  B$, so $\neg (\sup B \in A)$ is true....... If $B$ has an upper bound in $\Bbb R,$ then $\sup B$ exists in $\Bbb R$ because $B $ is also not empty. In this case, show that $[x,\sup B)\subset A$  Then show that $\forall r>0\;(\; \neg (\,[\sup  B,\,r+\sup B)\subset A\,)\;),$ implying $\sup B \not \in A $ 
 (because $A$ is open).

Comment: Your proof assumes that you can choose $x$ as you like ("If we take $x \in A$ to be very close to $\sup A$..."). But that is not how I understand the question, $x$ is *given* (witht the only condition that is must be in $A$) and the definition of $B$ then depends on $x$, so you must be proving the statement for all $x$, not just any you pick to your liking.
Hint: Consider the cases $[x,\infty) \subset A$ and $[x,\infty) \subsetneq A$. The first case makes it easy to calculate $\sup B$, the second may provide you a way out of your "what if $A$ is unbounded" problem.